# How to make splash screen run when user screen is disabled

Tags: android, android-layout

How to allow user to enable the location on the splash screen itself?

I have code in which there is a dialog box to enable user's location at the starting of app.

When the app starts first splash screen is visible for few seconds and if user's location is disabled then there will be a pop up to let the user enable location but at that time there is no background behind the dialog box.

I want  to load both the dialog box and splash screen at the same time (splash screen in background) if user's location is disabled.

Any ideas?

```
String status = null;
Bundle bundle = null;
StartLocationAlert startLocationAlert;
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 1;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    googleApiClient = getInstance();
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Boolean b1=    locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    LocationManager locationManager1 = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Boolean b2=locationManager1.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


    if (!b1&&!b2) {

        final Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    // Boolean b3=startLocationAlert.settingsrequest();

                    Log.e("settingsrequest","Comes");
                    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
                    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
                    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
                    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

                    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
                    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                            final Status status = result.getStatus();
                            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                                    break;
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                                    try {
                                        status.startResolutionForResult(SplashScreen.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                        Log.e("Applicationsett",e.toString());
                                    }

                                    break;
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Location is Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        // startLocationAlert = new StartLocationAlert(this);
        thread.start();

    } else {
        startActivityThread();
    }
}
public void startActivityThread(){
    final Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent intent = null;
                boolean loggedIn = false;
                SharedPreferences w = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor share = w.edit();
                loggedIn = (w.getBoolean("loggedIn", loggedIn));
                System.out.println("logged in " + loggedIn);
                if (loggedIn) {
                    intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, TestNavigationFragments.class);
                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Intent intent = null;
                    boolean loggedIn = false;
                    SharedPreferences w = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor share = w.edit();
                    loggedIn = (w.getBoolean("loggedIn", loggedIn));
                    System.out.println("logged in " + loggedIn);
                    if (loggedIn) {
                        intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, TestNavigationFragments.class);
                    } else {
                        intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
public  GoogleApiClient getInstance(){
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    return mGoogleApiClient;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some of your code so we can help you?

Comment: @RCaetano please find the updated post.

Comment: can anyone please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved using startresolutionForResult() method .result of this method is handled by onActivityResult() method.

in OnActivityResult() method handled the result of dialog box and only on click of yes the splash screen will sleep otherwise it will be in background of dialog box.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            final Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    super.run();
                    try {
                        sleep(2000);
                        finish();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        Intent intent = null;
                        boolean loggedIn = false;
                        SharedPreferences w = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor share = w.edit();
                        loggedIn = (w.getBoolean("loggedIn", loggedIn));
                        System.out.println("logged in " + loggedIn);
                        if (loggedIn) {
                            intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, TestNavigationFragments.class);
                        } else {
                            intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                        }
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```